# Frequency count of a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that I would like to store based on the frequency count.

```
a=[[list1],[list2],[list3],[list1]]
```

What I mean by a frequency count is efficiently creating an index-able structure with the unique lists and its occurrences.

```
{
  2: [list1]
  1: [list2]
  3: [list3]
}
```

For instance when it comes to a single list we have a dictionary with unique key-value pairs.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,6,2,2,1,3,6]
dict1={}
for i in a:
   if(i in dict1):
      dict1[i]+=1
   else:
      dict1[i]=1

 #output : {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 6: 2}
```

What would be the best way to go about this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if two lists both show up 5 times?  What should the value of the 5 key be?

Comment: I believe I wasn't clear with the explanation, I have updated with an example based on a list.

Comment: Did you mean `dict1[i]=1`?  Your example list has two `6`s, but your output has the mapping `6: 1`

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, you are right.

Comment: Do you know anything about the contents of the lists?  If you're trying to build a `lists: counts` dictionary, your best bet is to convert the lists into a hashable type, like `tuple`s, and use those as the keys.  That's only possible if the contents of the lists are themselves valid keys.

Comment: Tuples did the trick for me, can you verify what I have posted? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem is that I could not hash my lists to store the frequency count. So thanks to the helpful suggestion from Patrick in the comments session, I was able to use tuples, because it is a hashable type.

```
a=[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
di=[]
for i in a:
   i=tuple(i)
   di.append(i)
print(di)
dict1={}
for i in di:
   if(i in dict1):
      dict1[i]+=1
   else:
      dict1[i]=1
print (dict1)
```

This is not an eloquent piece of code, but at the moment this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your lists into  a tuple and use them as keys of a dictionary, which looks almost exactly like your code in the question.

```
a=[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
d = {}
for l in a:
    t = tuple(l)
    if t in d:
        d[t] += 1
    else:
        d[t] = 1
print(d)
```